# Error in bash when trying to use a var as a name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to do a very basic backup scripts for my laptop, the problem is that when I run my program I get an error that says 'date: extra operand' I searched with chatGPT and it doesn't help me.

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

date = "$(date +%D)"
tar -czf "/home/sebas/Backup/$date.tar.gz" "/home/sebas/{Documents,Desktop,Pictures,Videos}"
echo "Backup complete"
```

and got as result:

date: extra operand ‘10/08/23’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /home/sebas/{Documents,Desktop,Pictures,Videos}: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Backup complete

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here.

Comment: In addition to the incorrect blanks around the `=` in assignment, you also must not quote brace expansion, or the braces become literal.